# Collapse borders of nested DIVs

Tags: css, border

I have a problem styling nested DIVs ([see here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/wP3CB/)).

I have some nested DIVs (with `class="box"`) which are dynamically rendered, e.g:

```
<div class="box" id="1">
  other content
  <div class="box" id="2">
    <div class="box" id="3">
    </div>
  </div>
  other content
  <div class="box" id="4">
  </div>
</div>
other content
```

I'd like these DIVs to have a border at the bottom:

```
<style>
div.box {border-bottom: solid 1px gray;}
</style>
```

The problem is, when the bottom border of two nested DIVs are adjacent (e.g. box 2 and 3 or box 1 and 4), then the result is a gray line of 2 (or more pixels) height.

Is it possible to collapse the borders of nested DIVs, if they are adjacent?

I tried adding `border-collapse: collapse`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border collapse doesn't work, I got it working with your JsFiddle but you probably have to change it because you're DIVs are dynamically created.

```
div.box > div.box {
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
}

div.box > div.box > div.box:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: `:last-child` doesn't respect the class names, it only works if the **last child** of the parent element matching `div.box`.

Comment: Although to be fair if all the children are `div.box` anyway there's probably nothing wrong with using `:last-child`. Just something to keep in mind though.

Comment: Btw, the `other content` [may appear after the fourth `.box`](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/wP3CB/3/) element, in this case the box should have a border.

Answer (score 10):

[`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) property is only applicable to *table* and *inline-table* elements.

Try adding `margin-bottom` property to `.box` elements with a negative value to overlap the borders as follows:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/wP3CB/1/)**

```css
div.box {
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css property `border-collapse` works only with tables...

If you are using div then you can use `:last-child` selector of css3 to desable border on last .box element

e.g.

```
box .box:last-child{border:none;}
```

Comment: Again `:last-child` pseudo class represents the last child of its parent, This only works if the last child of the parent element matching `.box`.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to do that:

**1) Make your divs behave like table\table-cell elements.**

*HTML*

```
<div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

*SCSS*

```
.wrapper2 {
    display: table; border-collapse: collapse; margin-bottom: 15px;
    .row {
        width: 200px; height: 100px; background: green; border: 1px solid red; display: table-cell;    
    }
}
```

**2) Just select div you need and remove border from one side**

*HTML*

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

*SCSS*

```
.wrapper {
    width: 404px; margin-bottom: 15px;
    .row {
        width: 200px; height: 100px; background: green; border: 1px solid red; float: right;
        &:first-child { border-left: 0; }
    }
    .clearfix { clear: both; }
}
```

**3) Overlap divs**

*HTML*

```
<div class="wrapper3">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row move-left"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

*SCSS*

```
.wrapper3 {
    width: 404px; margin-bottom: 15px;
    .row {
        position: relative; width: 200px; height: 100px; background: green; border: 1px solid red; float: left;
        &.move-left { left: -1px }
    }
    .clearfix { clear: both; }
}
```

**All 3 examples on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsBYu/)**

Just pick something that till fit your project